# Git is not ignoring tmp files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitignore

I'm having this annoying issue in a Ruby On Rails application where git keeps committing these `tmp/` files. In my `.gitignore` file, I have `tmp/` so I don't understand why they keep showing up...here is my `.gitignore` file for reference:

```
# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp/

/public/system/*
/vendor/cache/

# OS generated cache files
Thumbs.db
DS_Store
```

It's just a minor issue that is getting annoying to my team and I on the repo. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Adding files to `.gitignore` _after_ you've already committed them is too late.  As @David Grayson has the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the files with `git rm`.  Maybe a command like this will work:

```
git rm -R tmp
```

Then make a commit to record that you have removed the files from git, and git will stop trying to track changes to those files.

Comment: `-R` is an invalid option. Perhaps, you tried to use `-r`.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 : specify all files in .gitignore**

/log/*
*.log
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

**Step 2: clear your git cache**
git rm -r --cached tmp/